# checkboxes not changing react native elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi I am doing a form like the component with checkboxes on react native that marks if the user is female or male, but I can't make it work it appears and looks like I want but I can't make the mark change from one option to the other one nor can I pass the value to submit

any help is appreciated

**Note:** that I am using the library `react-native-elements` for the `<CheckBox />` component.

this is my code

```
import React, {  useContext,useState} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

import MyDatePicker from './MyDatePicker';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

const PersonalForm = ({onSubmit, errorMessage}) => {
    const [vName, setvName] = useState('');
    const [vSecondName, setvSecondName] = useState('');
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(true);


return ( 
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Nombre"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvName => setvName(newvName)}
            value={vName}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
            placeholder="Segundo nombre"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            onChangeText={newvSecondName => setvSecondName(newvSecondName)}
            value={vSecondName}
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize='characters'
          />
          </View>
          </View>
          <CheckBox
            containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
            textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
            uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
            checkedColor={"#911830"}
            key={4}
            title="Male"
            value={4}
            value="4"
            checkedIcon="stop"
            checked={selectedValue}
            onChange={()=>setSelectedValue(true)}
          />
          <CheckBox
            containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
            textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
            uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
            checkedColor={"#911830"}
            key={3}
            title="Female"
            value={3}
            value="3"
            checkedIcon="stop"
            checked={!selectedValue}
            onChange={()=>setSelectedValue(false)}
          />
          <View>
              <MyDatePicker />
          </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer2}>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                style={ styles.logout}  
                onPress={() => onSubmit(vName, vSecondName, vGender, vEmail)}
              >
                  <Text style={styles.loginText}>GUARDAR</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the question to clearly specify that the library being used is `react-native-elements`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are using the callback wrong. As mentioned in the [docs](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html), the callback you are looking for is `onPress` instead of `onChange`.

Change it to this:

```
 <CheckBox
        containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
        textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
        uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
        checkedColor={"#911830"}
        key={4}
        title="Male"
        value={4}
        value="4"
        checkedIcon="stop"
        checked={selectedValue}
        onPress={()=>setSelectedValue(true)}
      />
     <CheckBox
        containerStyle={styles.checkbox}
        textStyle={styles.checkboxTxt}
        uncheckedColor={'#b3b4b5'}
        checkedColor={"#911830"}
        key={3}
        title="Female"
        value={3}
        value="3"
        checkedIcon="stop"
        checked={!selectedValue}
        onPress={()=>setSelectedValue(false)}
      />
```

Comment: Where does it say `onPress`? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/checkbox#onchange

Comment: @AkshitMehra he is using the Checkbox from react-native-elements. See my answer, which links to the correct docs. Please read correctly next time, and don't down vote because you misread.

Comment: @ignos555 My apologies! That's why I added a comment instead of just downvoting silently.